# Rails routing - a good way to split the edit form into separate parts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a pretty long edit form, and I would like to split it into separate sections. Say, I want to take out the user photo gallery and maybe address details into a separate view. My question is - what is the best practice to do that?

I assume my link should be looking like **post/23/edit/gallery** or **post/23/edit/address** would it be the Rails way? what kind of route does this require?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post/23/gallery/edit` looks more semantic. `gallery` - resource related to post and `edit` - action on this resource. actual modification will have `post/23/gallery`  url with POST, PUT, DELETE methods, which is more REST